# Why does MATLAB say that my array index must either be a positive integer or a logical value?

Tags: arrays, matlab

Here's the code section that I'm having trouble with:

```
function coeff(p, I) %linear coefficients for the adam-moulton method
    beta = [];
    syms u;
    B = 1;
    
    for j = 0 : (p-1)
        for i = 0 : (p-1)
            if ~(i == j)
                B = B * (u + i);
            end
        end
        beta = [beta, ((-1).^j)./( factorial(j) * factorial(p - j - 1) ) * integral(@(u) B(u), I(1), I(2))];
    end 
end
```

and MATLAB is telling me that right here:

```
beta = [beta, ((-1).^j)./( factorial(j) * factorial(p - j - 1) ) * integral(@(u) B(u), I(1), I(2))];
```

my array index must be a positive integer or a logical value, but I don't see why this should be an issue, since I'm simply trying to append to the pre-existing array beta. How could I make this work ?

Comment: In Matlab indexing starts with 1 not zero. Since, your loop variables are starting from zero, Matlab throws this exception. Your loop should start at 1 and go to `p` not `p-1`.

Comment: @Till, I don't think that's the problem, as there is never any call to `array(i)` or `array(j)`; if you don't do that, you can start your loops with 0, negative integers, or whatever integer you want. The problem is likely in the fact that `u` is a symbolic variable, and thus you can't have `B(u)`, but having never used the symbolic toolbox I can't be sure.

Comment: @MatteoV Do you happen to have an idea for a way to fix my code so that symbolic variables wouldn't be needed ?

Comment: @SardarUsama $p$ is as in $p$-step methods. $I$ is the interval over which my time parameter $t$ ranges. For visual convenience I take $I$ in as an array ```[a, b]``` and would then extract ```I(1)``` and ```I(2)``` from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral function needs an function with a function handle, you can transform B and adjust the integral statement;

```
for j = 0 : (p-1)
    for i = 0 : (p-1)
        if ~(i == j)
            B = B * (u + i);
        end
    end
    B = matlabFunction(B);
    beta = [beta, ((-1).^j)./( factorial(j) * factorial(p - j - 1) ) * integral(B, I(1), I(2))];
```